AttributeError: module 'ibis.selectors' has no attribute 'index'
I'm trying to select columns by index just like this reference from the ibis docs:
import ibis
import ibis.selectors as s
spotify = ibis.duckdb.connect()
spotify.read_csv("hf://datasets/maharshipandya/spotify-tracks-dataset/dataset.csv", table_name = "tracks")
tracks = spotify.table("tracks")
tracks.select(s.index[1:4])

I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'ibis.selectors' has no attribute 'index'. How can I properly select multiple columns using their numeric indexes?
I am using ibis==9.4.0.

The problem was my version. I was on ibis 9.4.0, but the reference docs are on version 9.5.0. The above code works fine with 9.5.0.
